# What is document.f.q.focus?

Tags: javascript

What is `document.f.q.focus`?

Is this a java script code or not

whether I can use `document.f.id.value`?

what is the difference between this and  `document.getElementbyID()`

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form name="f">
    <input name="q" />
</form>
```

In such a case, `document.f` refers to the form, and `.q` refers to the input element of that form. `.focus()` places the focus on that input.

It's worth noting that such code is unnecessary now that HTML5 is around:

```
<input name="q" autofocus />
```

Comment: so better we have document.getElementById('id').value?

Comment: is there any script I have to include for executing the above code

Comment: `name` and `id` are not the same thing, so `getElementById` will *not* work. `document.f.id` refers to either an input with `name="id"`, or the id of the form itself, so... yeah.

Answer (score 0):

It needs a form to make it work, Try this:

```
<form name="f">
    <input name="q" value="test" type="text"/>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
document.f.q.focus();
document.f.q.value = 1;
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/C58My/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute inside a html is meant to be unique.`name` can be an array(file[]) and with html5 should be used only on form elements.

html5 removed the support of the `name` atrribute on most elements except form elements.

`id` and `name` are 2 different things.

`document` refers to the whole html inside a page.

to get an element by it's `id` you need to call `document.getElementById(id);`

to get an element by it's `name` (considering html5) so inside a form

you call `document.forms[0].name`. `form[0]` refers to the first form inside the document

In your case the form has also a `name` so appart from html5 the code is correct.

`form` is called `f`,`input` is called `q`. thats why `document.f.q` returns the input field.

if you want to add an id to your input field then you have to add an `id`:

```
<input name="q" id="q">
```

to get the element:

```
document.getElementById('q');
```

to return the content:

```
document.getElementById('q').value;
```

And `focus();` is a native function that points the focus to the choosen element.
In your case when you load the page you will see the blinking pointer inside the searchflied.